# Pontryagin Principle for Random Process

Tags: control-theory

Can Pontryagin's principle be written for minimizing the expected cost in the case of a stochastic process which is controlled? (cost at each time is function of state and action)?? I have not come across any such formulation.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat dual method to PMP is called the dynamic programming (DP), in particular see the following [Bellman optimality principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman_equation). The rough idea is to split the total cost into the current part and the future part (which are often in the trade-of). It applies both to the deterministic systems, and stochastic systems. For the discrete time case see any book of [Bertsekas](http://www.mit.edu/~dimitrib/home.html), especially the one with Shreve, and for the continuous time case see any book on controlled diffusions, e.g. [that one](http://books.google.nl/books/about/Controlled_diffusion_processes.html?id=IYZF1Fci9n8C&redir_esc=y).